# Android ConstraintLayout - how to create chain with uneven space?

Tags: java, android, android-constraintlayout

[image: This is what i want to make]

How can i create this using ConstraintLayouts?
I want to have some views attached to the right, some to the left and variable space in the middle that depends on the length of the views on the right/left. I know about chains but they always add an even space between views, and i don't want to give a fixed value to the space. In a linear layout i would have done something like this:

```
<LinearLayout >
<ImageView />
<TextView />

<Space
android:layout_width="0dp"
android:layout_height="0dp"
android:layout_weight="1" />

<ImageView />
<ImageView />
<TextView />
<LinearLayout/>
```

Can this be replicable in ConstraintLayout?

Comment: Align the first two to the start, the last three to the end.

Comment: @Nicolas what happens if the length of the other views it's too big, wouldn't they overlap?

Comment: Yes, but you didn't say what behavior you wanted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why would you need chain or Space in between when you can directly use `Constraints` for individual elements. See this pseudo code, this can help.

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
  .....
  .....
>
<TextView
  .....
  app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
  app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
  android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
  android:drawableStart=" Your clock icon" //Using this you don't have to use a separate ImageView
 />
 <ImageView
  .....
  app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf=" ID of your Download Count TextView"
  app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
  android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
 />
 <TextView
  .....
  app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
  app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
  android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
  android:drawableStart=" Your Download icon"
 />
 </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

I've used `drawbleStart` instead of separate `ImageView` which you can use if you want to, just use `app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf=" ID of the View"`. The margins given are the space between the end/start of the screen and the view, you can adjust it as you want.

This will provide you the view you've shared. Check if this can help.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this using ConstraintLayout like this:

```
<ConstraintLayout >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/first"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="end"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/first"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"/>

</ConstraintLayout>
```